# how to verify if input email is already exist in database?

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have an issue with the program am trying to develop. I have a function that will send OTP code to user when they request to login. the OTP code should be sent through email to the registered users. the problem is that my code now accepts every email and it doesn't validate the users from the database. How can I do this?

UPDATED the new code!
I updated my code that i previously posted because initially I had issue in getting the OTP also. Someone helped me to point my mistake and I corrected them. But still the existing email verification has no luck. Please help!

this is my updated script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'>

{% block title %}

{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<h1>OTP Verification Page</h1>
<br>
<br>
<p>
    </script>
<div id="email_div" style="display: block;" >

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <button  onclick="ajax_send_otp()">Send OTP</button>
</div>
<div id="verify_text_div"></div>
<div id="otp_div" style="display: none;" >

    <label for="email">OTP</label>
    <input type="text" name="otp" id="otp">
    <button  onclick="verify_otp()">Verify</button>

</div>
</p>

{% endblock %}

<script>
     var otp_from_back="";
     function ajax_send_otp(){
        document.getElementById("email_div").style.display='none';
        email = document.getElementById("email");
      $.post("/send_otp",
          {
              "email":email.value,
              "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{csrf_token}}"
          },
          function(data, status){
              if(status=="success"){
                  otp_from_back = data;
                  document.getElementById("otp_div").style.display='block';
                  }
     }
     );
     }

    function verify_otp(){
        var user_otp=document.getElementById("otp").value;
        if (user_otp==otp_from_back){
            document.getElementById("verify_text_div").style.color="green";
            document.getElementById("verify_text_div").innerHTML="OTP Verified";
            setTimeout(window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/"),2000);
            document.getElementById("otp_div").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("form_div").style.display="block";

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("verify_text_div").style.color="red";
            document.getElementById("verify_text_div").innerHTML="Try Again!!";
        }
    }
 </script>
```

and this is my updated views.py file

```
def otp_verification(request):
    return render(request, 'otp.html')


def generateOTP():
    digits = "0123456789"
    OTP = ""
    for i in range(4):
        OTP += digits[math.floor(random.random() * 10)]
    return OTP


def send_otp(request):
    email = request.GET.get("email")
    print(email)
    o = generateOTP()
    #email = EmailMessage(
     #   subject='Nithya FYP OTP',
      #  body= ('OTP request', o),
       # from_email=EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        #to=[email],
    #)
    #mail.send()
    print(o)
    return HttpResponse(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try validating your email and checking if the email exists in your database.

```
email = request.POST['email']
if validate_email(email) and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
...
else:
...
```

Comment: hello @Ashin. I tried to implement this but still no luck. And I have updated the initial code I posted because I had few errors which I corrected. Please kindly take a look at it and it will be great if you could suggest further solution. Thank you.

Comment: I am a bit confused. The email is validated and the email is checked in the database if it exists or not in the code which I had mentioned. You've mentioned in your problem "the problem is that my code now accepts every email and it doesn't validate the users from the database. How can I do this ?".